Are prenups legally binding in England?
I have read that prenup agreements are not legally binding in England. Is this correct?

Do you mean England and Wales? Or England, Wales, and Scotland?

The question itself only mentions England. Presumably, that is what the OP is principally concerned with. Although you are right to mention Scotland separately as that would have made my answer different @MichaelHarvey

@FD_bfa - England and Wales share the same legal system.

Yes - that is why I stated that my answer would only be different for Scotland. However, more generally it is worth noting that Wales has held some devolved powers since 1998 (although that is not relevant to this particular question) @MichaelHarvey

Before 2010 pre-nuptial agreements were not generally considered legally binding in England. In 2010, this position changed following the Supreme Court case of Radmacher v Granatino [2010] UKSC 42.
Pre-nuptial agreements can now be enforced by the courts under s 25 of the Matrimonial Causes Act ("MCA") 1973 so long as the three-stage Radmacher test is met (see below) and it is considered fair to do so, keeping in mind the interests of any child of the family.

The Matrimonial Causes Act 1973

Section 25(1) of the MCA: the court prioritises the welfare of any minor children. If enforcing a prenup would negatively affect the children's welfare, the court will likely override it.

Section 25(2)(a) and (b) of the MCA: the court must consider each party's financial needs, resources, and earning capacity. If a prenup does not adequately provide for one party's needs, it is unlikely to be upheld in full.

Section 25(2)(c) of the MCA: if the terms of the prenup are inconsistent with the lifestyle the parties enjoyed during the marriage, the court may depart from its terms.

Section 25(2)(d) of the MCA: a prenup might hold less weight in a long marriage, especially if circumstances have significantly changed since it was signed.

Section 25(2)(f) of the MCA: non-financial contributions, such as raising children or homemaking, must also be accounted for, even if the prenup does not recognise them.



With the above considerations in mind, Radmacher holds that the courts will give effect to a pre-nuptial agreement that satisfies the following three-stage test (mentioned above).

The three-stage Radmacher test 2010
A pre-nuptial agreement will only be upheld if:

it is freely entered into by each party;

with a full appreciation of its implications; and

it is fair to hold the parties to their agreement.



The Law Commission has accepted the decision in Radmacher and recommended the creation of a qualifying nuptial agreement regime, although this has not happened as of yet.
In summary: Under the right conditions, pre-nuptial agreements can be enforced. However, there is certainly no automatic right for them to be enforced on the sole basis that both parties have signed it. The above provides a good understanding of the explicit law. To interpret this for specific situations, there is further guidance that can be found in many of the subsequent court decisions after the 2010 case.

Sounds like the third criterion is the sticking point that makes them basically worthless. If there's a significant difference in wealth, she's still taking half your stuff, which is the scenario you signed a prenup to avoid.

@nick012000 you can have a prenup that specifies a non 50-50 split, but it can't be 100-0. There's a bunch of room between those two

To illustrate the point made by @Caleth further, see the recent example of MN v AN [2023] EWHC 613 (Fam)

There, the husband successfully relied on a pre-nuptial agreement to pay his wife £11.75 million of his £44 million fortune - which is substantially less than half @nick012000
